# How to detect odd number of values and print out error message

Tags: c++

I am trying to read values from a text file by pairs and do multiplication and addition on them.

This is how the text file looks like:

[image]

This is my code:

```
while (inFile >> positiveIntegerOne >> positiveIntegerTwo)
{
    if (positiveIntegerOne < 1) {
        if (positiveIntegerTwo < 1) {
            validIntegers = false;
            cout << "Integer one = " << positiveIntegerOne << "   Integer two = " << positiveIntegerTwo << "   Integer two is less than 1. \n";
        }
        validIntegers = false;
        cout << "Integer one = " << positiveIntegerOne << "   Integer two = " << positiveIntegerTwo << "   Integer one is less than 1. \n";
    }
    else {
        integersMultiplied = positiveIntegerOne * positiveIntegerTwo;
        integersAdded = positiveIntegerOne + positiveIntegerTwo;
        cout << "Integer one = " << positiveIntegerOne << "   Integer two = " << positiveIntegerTwo << "   Multipled = " << integersMultiplied << "   Added = " << integersAdded << "\n";
    }

}
```

If I run the code, the result looks like this:

[image]

But as you can see, I have odd number of values in the text file (8 doesn't belong to a pair). I need my code to automatically detect that, and still do the calculations on the pairs, then print out an error message like "Input file has odd number of values" in the end

So ideally, the result should look like this:

[image]

I tried to add another if statement after the else (and outside of the loop), but it's not working

```
    if (!(positiveIntegerTwo))
    {
        cout << "Input file has odd number of values\n";
    }
```

Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: @drescherjm I think I know what you misunderstood, I wasn't saying there cannot be any odd numbers on my file, what I meant was if "the amount of numbers was odd", then display the error message

Comment: @drescherjm if there are 7 numbers in my file, then I need to do calculations on the first 6 number (3 pairs), then bec the last number (the 7th number) doesn't belong to a pair, I need to print out the error message. If there are 6 numbers in the file, then I simply do calculation on them and end the program

Comment: @drescherjm that's why I thought % is meaningless in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do the following.

```
while (inFile >> positiveIntegerOne)
{
    if (inFile >> positiveIntegerTwo) {
        // You have a pair of numbers!
        if (positiveIntegerOne < 1) {
            if (positiveIntegerTwo < 1) {
                validIntegers = false;
                cout << "Integer one = " << positiveIntegerOne << "   Integer two = " << positiveIntegerTwo << "   Integer two is less than 1. \n";
            }
            validIntegers = false;
            cout << "Integer one = " << positiveIntegerOne << "   Integer two = " << positiveIntegerTwo << "   Integer one is less than 1. \n";
        }
        else {
            integersMultiplied = positiveIntegerOne * positiveIntegerTwo;
            integersAdded = positiveIntegerOne + positiveIntegerTwo;
            cout << "Integer one = " << positiveIntegerOne << "   Integer two = " << positiveIntegerTwo << "   Multipled = " << integersMultiplied << "   Added = " << integersAdded << "\n";
        }

    }
    else {
        // Print error for odd # of values!
    }
}
```

The difference is you loop reading 1 number at a time but then try to read the next number. If that succeeds you have a pair, if it fails there is an error

Comment: One thing this does not handle is lines. If you wanted to validate each line that it must contain exactly 2 numbers the code would be a little different. In that case you could use `std::getline()` into a string and `istringstream` to get the 2 numbers out of the string.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have to worry about lines. For what I tested so far, your code worked! I have to log off now, but I will do some study on your code. Thanks!